# How to show validation message during save if the input field is not number in angular2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

i have used ng2-completer. So here based on search by code or name i am able to get dropdown values.During save if the input value is still text, the popup must throw saying, it must be a number not text in alert.
How can that be handled? 
Here i cant limit in the input field because i need to perform search there on basis of name and code, to get the dropdown values.

HTML:

```
<ng2-completer inputClass="form-control" formControlName="code" [datasource]="dataService" [minSearchLength]="0" [openOnClick]="true" (input)="handleStaticResultSelected($event.target.value)" placeholder="Search Group Agent"
              ></ng2-completer>
```

TS:

```
this.searchForm = this.FB.group({
        code: [null,Validators.required],
})

save(){
console.log(this.searchForm.value)
}
```

Comment: In your save function you can check the value is Number or not (if (Number (this.searchForm.value)) and then set alert. Just take care about NaN (isNaN(this.searchForm.value)) Hope this will help.

Comment: thanks for the response i will check and update you

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked for me, could you please post it as an answer

Comment: I have posted the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your save function you can check the value is Number or not

```
    (if (Number (this.searchForm.value)){
alert('Yes number');

}
```

and then set alert. 
Just take care about NaN (isNaN(this.searchForm.value))